# Writing string list to a txt file, but the file is empty why?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

```
import re, urllib.request

patern = re.compile(r'image/\w*\W*\w*\.\jpg', re.I|re.M)

file = open('APODLinks.txt','r')
rf = file.read()
a = rf.split('\n')
file.close()


def lic(li):
    if not li:
        pass
    else:
        print(li[0])
        f.write('http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/%s\n' % li[0])


def main():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        ur = urllib.request.urlopen(a[i])
        mf = re.findall(patern, str(ur.read()))
        lic(mf)

f = open('APODImgs.txt','w')
main()
f.close()
```

What's wrong with my code i'm try to write a txt file with all the jpg pictures
from Astronomy picture of the day but the file APODImgs.txt is empty...
The mf list some times is empty maybe this is my problem...

The APODLinks.txt contain urls like this:

```
apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap140815.html
apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap140814.html
apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap140813.html
```

7000 lines of urls

The APODImgs.txt must be like this:

```
apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1408/Persei93_1abolfath.jpg
apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1408/Supermoon_20140810.JPG
apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1408/m57_nasagendler_3000.jpg
apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1408/HebesChasma_esa_1024.jpg
...
```

Please help and sorry for my English...

Comment: It doesn't affect your pattern, but the `'j'` in `'\jpg'` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: I copied your code and tried it out, using the example files you have. It seemed to work once I added "http://" to the beginning of the links in APODLinks.txt. Also, you can just have a = file.readlines()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I change my code and it works!!!**

```
import re, urllib.request

patern = re.compile(r'image/\w*\W*\w*\.jpg', re.I|re.M)

file = open('APODLinks.txt','r')
rf = file.read()
a = rf.split('\n')
file.close()


def lic(li):
    if not li:
        print("No matches found")  
    else:
        print('http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/%s' % li[0])
        f.write('http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/%s\n' % li[0])


def main():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        try:
            ur = urllib.request.urlopen(a[i])
        except:
            print('404 not found!')
        mf = re.findall(patern, str(ur.read()))
        lic(mf)

f = open('APODImgs.txt','w')
main()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably `not li` is always true in `lic`, because your regexp doesn't match.

To figure it out, print the HTTP response body:

```
urr = urllib.request.urlopen(a[i]).read()
print repr(urr)
mf = re.findall(patern, urr)
print repr(mf)
lic(mf)
```

Comment: my regexp is fine... some urls have video or images in other format. Because of that my list is empty... When i run the script, the line print(li[0]) works print out all ulrs but the APODImgs.txt is empty...

Comment: Add an `f.flush()` call right after the `f.write(...)`, and add a `print('WRITING:' + repr(li[0]))` just above it. What is the exact console output of your program then, and what is the size of the file?

Are you sure you are not trying to view the file while your program is running? Are you sure you don't abort your program before it finishes? Are you sure that the program is not aborting because of an uncaught exception?